# How to use warn_only option with "local" command in Python fabric?

Tags: fabric

Using warn_only with "run" and "sudo" is ok. But with "local", it produces the error below:

```
TypeError: local() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn_only'
```

Should I use env.warn_only=True instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thats the kind of thing that you forget and then comes and bites you in the butt. If you can avoid accessing `env` altogether will be fantastic at least while you're still familiarizing yourself with fabric. Instead, i humbly suggest you use `with setting(warn_only=True)` that way you only override it momentarily.

```
@task
@setting(warn_only=True)
def task_that_always_throws_warning():
    local('sudo ....')
    local('sudo ....') # if this throws an error you will NOT know about it


@task
def task_that_always_throws_warning_but_i_need_to_catch_the_second_local():
    with setting(warn_only=True):
        local('sudo ....')
    local('sudo ....') # if this throws an error you will know about it
```

---

you can also do this, (though i dont recommend it):

```
env.warn_only=True

@task
def task_that_always_throws_warning_but_i_need_to_catch_the_second_local():
    local('sudo ....')
    with setting(warn_only=False):
        local('sudo ....') # if this throws an error you will know about it
```

---

Bottom line is you can do it how ever you want, "im" a big fan of NOT overriding a systems defaults.